# Click is working but it throws error org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible

Tags: selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver, element

I have used cssselector, xpath and linktext for clicking a drop-down list item and all works fine and it clicks the element however the exception ElementNotVisibleException is thrown at the same time! There is no duplicate element also in the DOM.

I was using selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0 and also tried updating it to 2.48.2 but the error is still there. 
Tried it on both firefox and chrome but results the same. Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide brief HTML and selectors you used to identify the element

Answer (score 0):

Try to click your button using JavascriptExecutor.

Use below code to click on button

```
WebElement element= driver.findElement(YOUR LOCATOR for button);

JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Hope it will help you :)